# In Java coding convention, for multiline if condition, where to place the logical operators?

Tags: java, conventions

In the multiline `if` condition, I would like to know if we follow a convention where to place the logical operators (`&&`, `||`) or if it's just a **preference**.

Say we have this kind of `if` condition below:

```
Bird bird = new ...; // Some bird species
if (!bird.canFly() && bird.hasWings() && bird.hasFeathers() && bird.canSwim() || ...) {
...
}
```

With the long `if` condition above, for readability we just might do a multiline `if` condition.

For the logical operators, where do we put them? Is it in **left** or **right**?

Personally, I'm placing them on the **left** side so I know which operator is used in the following condition.

Am I doing it right, or wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official Java SE coding conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-indentation.html):

> **4.2 Wrapping Lines:**
>
> When an expression will not fit on a single line, break it according to these general principles:
>
> - Break after a comma.
> - Break before an operator.

So the operator goes to the new line, on the left.